# Resizing Photoshop CS6 from 30" Cinema display to 21" iMac (OS 10.8.5)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, workspace

I am using old Photoshop CS6 on 21" iMac (OS 10.8.5) with 30" Cinema display. When I take only my iMac on a trip, if I had Photoshop sized for the 30" display, the bottom right of the workspace runs outside the 21" active monitor. How can I resize it to fit without having the 30" to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long time since I've seen Mountain Lion or CS6... I'm presuming you can't see the red/yellow/green dots at top left of the window?

If you can, the green dot will resize it.

If you can't,  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>  & drag any visible window edge will resize the entire window equally [I hope that functionality existed at 10.8]. Once you can see all 4 sides, you can then drag them out to the correct edges again individually if needed.

If that doesn't work, see if the window will just drag down the screen - I've known the title bar with the dots to hide itself under the menu bar, which most Mac Apps can't do.

Comment: Thanks. One more thing: I do not remember what I did, but I was able to shrink the workspace to the exact size of the drawing, but now it stays like that. I prefer being able to have the workspace larger than the drawing (how it originally was). Do you know how to undo what I did?

Comment: cmd/0 [zero not 'oh'] will size to viewport. btw - If the answer helped, please mark it as 'accepted' with the check/tick mark & give it an upvote too ;-)